# catalog_product_collection_load_after causing maximum nesting issue for configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, event-observer

i have written modules that changes price of all products on product details page, including related showing on bottom .

**what modules does** 
here i am passing some product id in get parameter and adding price of it in all products on product detail page

**Issue facing**
My module works fine for simple products issue comes **$_GET['id']** is id of configurable product.

**Error i get** 
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting! in PATH\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 117

after debug found calling **$pricetoadd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setSkipCustomPriceObserver(true)->load($_GET['id']);**  causes error when $_GET['id'] is configurable products id why so ?

**config.xml**

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <setname>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>modifyallname</method>
        </setname>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
```

**Observer.php**

```
    public function modifyallname(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $products = $observer->getCollection();
        foreach( $products as $product )
        {

            if($_GET['id']==""){
                break;
            }
            $pricetoadd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setSkipCustomPriceObserver(true)->load($_GET['id']); 
            //this will set a flag that will be handled by the if statement above. If this flag is true your code will not be executed.
            $originalprice = $product->getPrice();

            $model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');
            $currentattribid = (int)$product->getAttributeSetId();

            $customprice = $originalprice+$pricetoadd->getPrice();

            if ($customprice > 0) {
                $product->setFinalPrice($customprice);
                $product->setMinimalPrice($customprice);
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: have you posted  $_GET['id'] via form or get current product?

Comment: in url like ?id=11

Comment: @Abdul can you help me with issue